# Does list operations load whole data at first call?

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

Suppose I've got very big collection and I select it by

```
MongoCursor<MyClass> answer = myCollection.find().as(MyClass.class);
```

Will Jongo/Mongo load whole collection at the first call or incrementally load data while I will iterate over `answer`?

Comment: Are you concerned about the memory usage of MongoDB (server side) or of Jongo (client side) ?

Comment: I'm concerned about client-side memory usage - I don't want to load whole collection into app memory

Comment: *GetCollection doesn't load the collection, not even a Find() will. In fact, you'll have to start iterating the MongoCursor before anything is actually loaded from the database, and even then, it won't load the entire collection but only batches of configurable size* [Answered Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298949/does-mongodb-getcollection-method-load-the-entire-collection-into-ram-or-a-refer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jongo's `MongoCursor` uses Mongo's regular `DBCursor` under the hood. The `DBCursor` loads elements lazily (as typically all cursors do). I.e., your whole collection will not be loaded into memory, it will be lazily loaded while you iterate through your cursor.

Relevant source from Jongo where `cursor` is a `DBCursor`.

```
public E next() {
    if (!hasNext())
        throw new NoSuchElementException();

    DBObject dbObject = cursor.next();
    return resultHandler.map(dbObject);
}
```